# react native textinput takes the value from another textinput

Tags: react-native

when I enter the number of items in the *textInput* **Item number**, i hope the price of the item automatically appears in the *textIinput* **Price**.
here is my quick script that won't work

please help me to improve, thank you

```
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            qty: 0, 
            prc: 0,
        }
    }

    price = () =>{
        var price = this.state.qty * 250;
        this.setState({ 
            prc: price,
        })
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                .....
                        <View style={{...}}>
                            <Text style={{...}}>Item number :</Text>
                            <TextInput
                                ...
                                onChangeText={(entry) => {
                                    this.setState({qty: entry})
                                    this.price();
                                }}
                                ...
                            />
                        </View>
                        <View style={{...}}>
                            <Text style={{...}}>Price :</Text>
                            <TextInput
                                ....
                                value={this.state.prc}
                                onChangeText={(entry) => {
                                    this.setState({prc: entry})
                                }}
                                ....
                            />
                        </View>
            </View>
```

Comment: @proyo p was you able to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like below

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
    <Text>Item number :</Text>
    <TextInput
        value={this.state.qty}
        onChangeText={(entry) => {
            this.setState({
                qty: entry,
                prc: entry * 250
            })
        }}
    />
    <Text>Price :</Text>
    <TextInput
        value={this.state.prc}
        onChangeText={(entry) => {
            this.setState({
                prc: entry
            })
        }}
    />
</View>
```

If you really want to use function `price` provide it as a **callback** function.

```
<TextInput
    value={this.state.qty}
    onChangeText={(entry) => {
        this.setState({
            qty: entry
        }, () => this.price())

    }}
/>
```

**Edit** - I have added a sample application check this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default class Example extends Component {
    state = {
        qty: 0,
        prc: 0,
    }

    price = () => {
        let price = this.state.qty * 250;
        this.setState({
            prc: price,
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Item number :</Text>
                <TextInput
                    value={this.state.qty}
                    onChangeText={(entry) => {
                        this.setState({
                            qty: entry
                        }, () => this.price())

                    }}
                />
                <Text>Price :</Text>
                <TextInput
                    value={this.state.prc}
                    onChangeText={(entry) => {
                        this.setState({
                            prc: entry
                        })
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: I have fixed it using those two models but it has no effect, the _text input_ **Price** remains zero, is there any other way, thank you

Comment: @priyop it should work. Anyway, I edit my answer with a sample code check that & let me know if it not work.

Comment: thank you @SDushan for the script example, I tried to make the app, it still can't run as expected, the _textinput_ **Price** still zero, thank you for your help

Comment: @priyop could you share whole source code, there might be an issue with your code.

Comment: @priyop any update? You can replace your source code with above code & run again.

Comment: I have fixed it but it still doesn't work as it should, even the sample source code from you I made the app still not working ...?

Comment: @priyop could you update your source code with the question

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
```

import { View, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default Example = () => {

```
const [price, setprice] = useState(0);
return (
    <View>
        <Text>Item number :</Text>
        <TextInput
            onChangeText={(entry) => setprice(entry)}
        />
        <Text>Price :</Text>
        <TextInput defaultValue={(parseInt(price) * 250).toString()}></TextInput>
    </View>
);
```

}